# I am getting a 'str' object has no attribute 'get' error (Python) with Tkinter Entry Box

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, get, tkinter-entry

I am currently working on a project where I will have a plethora of equations and laws from different subject areas within a calculator with GUI functionality. This project is a learning process and all help is appreciated. I am currently having trouble with the `Tkinter` Entry boxes, more specifically retrieving the values behind string variables. Every time I attempt to use `.get()` my Entry boxes return an error, `'str' object has no attribute 'get'`, which I can't figure out. I would also really appreciate if someone could help trim the fat of my code and minimize the bulk.

The issue is occurring in `class ReactionProp()` in **Science_Calculator.py**. Thanks to all who respond!

P.S. Sorry about weird formatting lol

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import math

"""    Calculator     """     
class CalculatorGUI(tk.Tk):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       
       tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       container = tk.Frame(self)

       container.pack(expand = True)

       container.grid_rowconfigure(0)
       container.grid_columnconfigure(0)

       self.frames = {}

       for F in ([ReactionProp]):

           frame = F(container, self)

           self.frames[F] = frame

           frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NS)

       self.show_frame(ReactionProp)

   def show_frame(self, cont):

       frame = self.frames[cont]
       frame.tkraise()

class ReactionProp(tk.Frame):       
   def __init__(self, parent, controller):
       tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
       
       checkT = tk.DoubleVar(self)
       r1 = tk.StringVar(self)
       r2 = tk.StringVar(self)
       r3 = tk.StringVar(self)
       r4 = tk.StringVar(self)
       r5 = tk.StringVar(self)
       p1 = tk.StringVar(self)
       p2 = tk.StringVar(self)
       p3 = tk.StringVar(self)
       p4 = tk.StringVar(self)
       p5 = tk.StringVar(self) 
       
       """    Activation Code     """
       def SolveReactionProp():
           Calculate = Calculator()  #Refers to Calculator Class
           
           r1 = ''
           r2 = ''
           r3 = ''
           r4 = ''
           r5 = ''
           p1 = ''
           p2 = ''
           p3 = ''
           p4 = ''
           p5 = ''
           
           if r1.get():
               r1 = var1.get()
           if z2.get():
               r2 = var2.get()
           if r3.get():
               r3 = var3.get()
           if r4.get():
               r4 = var4.get()
           if r5.get():
               r5 = var5.get()
           if p1.get():
               r6 = var6.get()
           if p2.get():
               r7 = var7.get()
           if p3.get():
               r8 = var8.get()
           if p4.get():
               r9 = var9.get()
           if p5.get():
               r10 = var10.get()
                       
           Calculate.ReactionProp()
       
       Label(self, text='Thermodynamics - Reaction Properties', font='Helvetica 24 bold').grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=4,padx=(100),pady=(0,30))
       
       Radiobutton(self,text='Temperature (K)',font='Helvetica 14',variable=checkT,value=1).grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=EW,pady=(0,25))
       Radiobutton(self,text='No Temperature',font='Helvetica 14',variable=checkT,value=0).grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=EW,pady=(0,25))
       tE = Entry(self,width=40)
       tE.grid(row=1,column=2,columnspan=2,pady=(35,0),sticky=W)
   
       Label(self, text='Reactants:',font='Helvetica 14').grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=2)
       r1 = Entry(self,width=40)
       r1.grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan=2,pady=(25,0))
       r2 = Entry(self,width=40)
       r2.grid(row=5,column=0,columnspan=2,pady=(25,0))
       r3 = Entry(self,width=40)
       r3.grid(row=6,column=0,columnspan=2,pady=(25,0))
       r4 = Entry(self,width=40)
       r4.grid(row=7,column=0,columnspan=2,pady=(25,0))
       r5 = Entry(self,width=40)
       r5.grid(row=8,column=0,columnspan=2,pady=(25,0))
       
       Label(self, text='Products:',font='Helvetica 14').grid(row=3,column=2,columnspan=2)
       p1 = Entry(self,width=40)
       p1.grid(row=4,column=2,columnspan=2,pady=(25,0))
       p2 = Entry(self,width=40)
       p2.grid(row=5,column=2,columnspan=2,pady=(25,0))
       p3 = Entry(self,width=40)
       p3.grid(row=6,column=2,columnspan=2,pady=(25,0))
       p4 = Entry(self,width=40)
       p4.grid(row=7,column=2,columnspan=2,pady=(25,0))
       p5 = Entry(self,width=40)
       p5.grid(row=8,column=2,columnspan=2,pady=(25,0))
       
       Button(self, text="Solve", font ='Helvetica 12 bold', command=SolveReactionProp).grid(row=9,column=1,pady=(100,0))
       Button(self, text="Return", font='Helvetica 12 bold', command=lambda:[controller.show_frame(ThermoTab)]).grid(row=9,column=2,pady=(100,0))

start  = CalculatorGUI()
start.mainloop()
```

Error Code:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Heath\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Heath\Documents\Science Calculator Project\untitled0.py", line 69, in SolveReactionProp
    if r1.get():
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: `r1` in `if r1.get()` is a string. I think `if var1.get()` is what you want.  Same applies to subsequent `if` statements.

Comment: Why do you think a string has a `get` method? You're clearly setting the variable to a string almost immediately before calling that method.

Comment: What is that, 500 lines of code with dozens of .get? Write a small piece of code the demonstrates the problem. One of the advantages of python is that it easy to write experimental scripts.

Comment: Sorry I shortened the code so it focuses on the issue

Comment: There are few issues in your code.  First using same variable for both `tk.StringVar()` and `Entry()`, e.g. `r1 = tk.StringVar()` and `r1 = Entry(self,width=40)`.  Second you actually create local variables inside `SolveReactionProp()`, e.g. `r1 = ''` etc., which then be used in `r1.get()` which raises the exception.  You need to think carefully how to refactor your code.

Comment: Thanks, I had just figured it out before saw this lol. I was just being dumb. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in **SolveReactionProp** function.You must remove this.

```
       r1 = ''
       r2 = ''
       r3 = ''
       r4 = ''
       r5 = ''
       p1 = ''
       p2 = ''
       p3 = ''
       p4 = ''
       p5 = ''
```

> Explanation:
> In **SolveReactionProp** You  typecasted or defined r1,r2 and other variables as python strings. So when you use **.get()** function you got the error because .get() is attribute of tk.StringVar() not of python strings.